# Node insertion binary tree C++

Tags: c++, tree

I believe i implemented inserting a new node into a binary search tree, however my testing script shows my tree as being in valid

My code where the value is inserted into the tree if there is no current node.

```
bool InsertRecursive(BinaryTreeNode* tree_node, int value) {

 if (tree_node == NULL)
 {

BinaryTreeNode * pNode = new BinaryTreeNode;
pNode->data = value;   // inserting node in
pNode->left_child = NULL;
pNode->right_child = NULL;
tree_node = pNode ; 
return true;
 }
       if(tree_node->data == value )   // if value already exists return false
{
 return false ; 
  }
   else if (tree_node->data > value)   // traverses to find the location for the value
    return InsertRecursive(tree_node->right_child, value);
  else 
return InsertRecursive(tree_node->left_child, value);

 }
```

the actual method of inserting the node inside

```
 bool BinaryTree::Insert(int value) {

if (InsertRecursive(head, value)) {
return true;
} else
  return false;
}
```

What my testing script says

|   Test: Insert

**|   |   -Should be a valid tree of size 1 after inserting '4'**

|   |   |   You built an invalid tree. Why would you do that to me?

**|   |   -Should be a valid tree of size 2 after inserting '2'**

|   |   |   You built an invalid tree. Your code needs to get it's life together

|   |   -Should be a valid tree of size 3 after inserting '3'

|   |   |   **You built an invalid tree. More coffee maybe?**

|   |   -Insert(1) should return false for: [ d2-1 d1-2 d2-3 d0-4 d2-5 d1-6 d2-7

]
**|   |   |   It returned true. Unlike a boss**
|   Failed!

So the problem should be with in where i actually insert the node as the tree is being read as in valid.  I am lost on how to solve this however and would like some guidance.

Comment: `tree_node` is a local variable. All you've done is create a memory leak.

Comment: I think you're traversing the wrong way..  if tree_node->data is >, you need to traverse left (and vice versa)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. I suggest you 1) think about what "`tree-node` is a local variable" means until it's clear what's going wrong, and 2) implement some linked lists flawlessly before you attempt trees.

Answer (score 0):

when leave fuction, "tree_node = pNode ;" effect nothing. change tree_node type to "BinaryTreeNode**"  if you want change it's value

Answer (score 0):

You have to split the inserts into both the helper and the method for each case of when head is equal to `nullptr` and when `tree_node` is equal to `nullptr`. Then add your implementations to both of those.

Your insert functions look like they are are on the right track so just think about how the two functions in the helper and the method are similar.

Comment: and just as a note, you will get a seg fault if you write BinaryTreeNode* pNode = new BinaryTreeNode. change it to BinaryTreeNode* pNode = new BinaryTreeNode{0}.